# Signature overload does not work as expected: Record vs Map

Tags: typescript

This is a pretty simple use case.

I have an overloaded signature which sometime accepts a Record, sometime a Map. Although I am using the Map version, somehow TS thinks I'm using the Record one. Why ? How should I fix this ?

```js
function doStuff(arg: Record<any, any>): Record<any, any>;
function doStuff(arg: Map<any, any>): Map<any, any>;
function doStuff(arg: any) {
  return arg;
}
    
let m: Map<any, any> = doStuff(new Map<any, any>());
// error ! m is returned as a Record
```

also see [the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgZSiYwAUBDAJwHMAuRAJQFMI4DkAePMATwBpEnmA%20ASjKpp1GLdpy4BuAFChIsBCnSZs%20YmQCyeAA7C2HFr3Vado-VOnho8JKgxZchUnuY9EAb0mJEBSpgJIHUgC%20kpIANj6IALaG2pwm3IgAvAq2ymCUAO6IGrEiTlw4PDxSQA)

Comment: might not be the answer you are looking for but couldn't you just make it generic ? `function doStuff<T>(arg: T): T;`

Comment: also i think it takes the first definition because map can be seen as a record

Comment: @HenriDev I think the problem with your suggested implementation is that this doesn't limit the use of the function to other types (here I think the author doesn't want `doStuff(3)` to be a valid call)

Comment: `function doStuff<T extends Record<any, any>>(arg: T ): T;` this should do the job :)

Comment: `Record<any, any>` is essentially any object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: you need to swap your two call signatures like this:

```
function doStuff(arg: Map<any, any>): Map<any, any>;
function doStuff(arg: Record<any, any>): Record<any, any>;
function doStuff(arg: any) {
  return arg;
}
```

---

The type `Record<any, any>` (using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype)) is equivalent to `{[x: string]: any}`:

```
type RecordAnyAny = Record<any, any>;
// type RecordAnyAny = {[x: string]: any}
```

an object-like type with a `string` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) whose properties are of [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any).  So it can have any keys at all, and any values at all.  So just about any object will be assignable to it:

```
let r: RecordAnyAny
r = {}; // okay
r = {a: 0, b: "one", c: true}; // okay
r = new Date(); // okay;
r = new Map(); // okay, note well
```

As you can see, even [a `Map` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is assignable to `Record<any, any>`.

---

On the other hand, the `Map<K, V>` type is [an `interface` defined in the TypeScript library](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/6834969f8f20d0cf64a40cc8d146a1be3d5440b0/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#L21-L29) as something like:

```
interface Map<K, V> {
    clear(): void;
    delete(key: K): boolean;
    forEach(callbackfn: (value: V, key: K, map: Map<K, V>) => void, thisArg?: any): void;
    get(key: K): V | undefined;
    has(key: K): boolean;
    set(key: K, value: V): this;
    readonly size: number;
}
```

And `Map<any, any>` is equivalent to the above interface with `any` substituted in for both `K` and `V`.

This type is more restrictive than `Record<any, any>`.  If I have a value `m` of type `Map<any, any>`, I *know* that it will have, say, a `get()` method, but with `Record<any, any>`, I *don't* know that, so it's not safe to use a `Record<any, any>` as a `Map<any, any>` (while it *is* safe to do the reverse):

```
let m: Map<any, any> = new Map();
m = r; // error
// Type 'RecordAnyAny' is missing the following properties from
//  type 'Map<any, any>': clear, delete, forEach, get, and 8 more.(2740)
```

So, hopefully this is clear: every `Map<any, any>` is a `Record<any, any>`, but not every `Record<any, any>` is a `Map<any, any>`.

---

Now we can look at your [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```
// call signatures 
function doStuffOld(arg: Record<any, any>): Record<any, any>;
function doStuffOld(arg: Map<any, any>): Map<any, any>;

// implementation
function doStuffOld(arg: any) {
  return arg;
}

doStuffOld(new Map<any, any>());
```

When you call an overloaded function, the compiler picks the *first matching call signature*.  So for `doStuffOld(new Map<any, any>())`, the compiler examines the first call signature `(arg: Record<any, any>) => Record<any, any>`.  Does it work?  **YES.**  Every `May<any, any>` is also a `Record<any, any>`, so the compiler selects this overload.  And so the return type is also `Record<any, any>`, and it's an error to assign the result to a `Map<any, any>`:

```
m = doStuffOld(new Map<any, any>()); // error!
```

The second call signature is never reached. Oops.

---

Because `Map<any, any>` is more specific than `Record<any, any>`, you need to swap the order of your two call signatures.  This advice is also given in [the TypeScript Handbook's Do's and Don'ts for function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#ordering):

```
// call signatures
function doStuff(arg: Map<any, any>): Map<any, any>;
function doStuff(arg: Record<any, any>): Record<any, any>;

// implementation
function doStuff(arg: any) {
  return arg;
}

m = doStuff(new Map<any, any>()); // okay
r = doStuff({a: 0, b: "one", c: true}); // okay
```

Now when you call `doStuff(new Map<any, any>())`, the compiler tries the `Map` call signature first.  That matches, so you get the `Map` return type.

And when you call `doStuff({a: 0, b: "one", c: true})`,  the compiler tries the `Map` call signature but it does not match (since that object is not a `Map`), so it then tries the `Record` call signature which does match... and you get the `Record` return type.

So now everything should work as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGB7ATgEwIIDsRZFAvLAiqgDwCG2ANFJSAHwDcAUAPStSiRFJq64EoAbwDaADwBcUAM7BkAS0wBzALpS6AX2bMANhGBRkUuLwzZczZIKEbGUdlEQBrciEvXyUgAw0ARlIAiREwIAJp4KTkAVwhbew5nV3dCEIB3KAARcmAIAAoASjsHRJAWKxSIdIBZcjACooSXN119KABbKRqwCmpabHpBNKgu+uY2wWQGqAhkZBQ2DgAVcGgAchMSfmxVqHlpdr3pRSVOAAtoADNEHR1EVOOoMDnIZGB5CH2LubaFqE4VqCrLo9EA0Oj0VZSeB6cjIGioCB6HI0K7IACi5HgpxoSn0YMwqCgAA52igIAA6XIAJgA7AAWLz5bS-eDkG4yeRKTDZKLID5QZgXKKYeBvYJQVCIADKwCiFwuAHkdKhcrClMZiGgQfiGPkNaZtX0GCwhSKxZgJdLZfKlSq1Z1aobwXrho66DqmL95G0wHo2hBMMBsvJgoLhaKQxbJTK5YrlarkOqjflhMw-nzZcgLWqWFoxoJo9a4yqhsD3Ub6AVCvFprMUABCZmmiPiwuxhNJsu9Z0O7rl8Em8Pmy0x+Ud-UkJ39F0bLX9-qDs2RkdF8fJ1Pp-S87OJ3PacaENtj0tu7v9KtTErJFftoSeKA+KD+KBBEJhKARTjIGIaavFJrMkAA)

Answer (score 0):

`Record<any, any>` is a type, while `Map<any, any>` is a value that "extends" `Record`, when you pass a `Map` value the first signature that coincides whit the call is the first one, and that's why Typescript see a call of `dostuff(Record<any, any>)` correctly returning a `Record<any, any>`.

`Record` is not assignable to `Map` for the reason above, this is why Typescript raise an error.

You should overload with just `Record` or `Map`